# MongoDB Aggregation - Dynamic `$addField`

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following object in the format `_id: userID` and a Mongoose query:

```
const obj = {
    111: "222",
    333: "444",
    555: "666"
};

Model.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            userID: ???
        }
    }
]);
```

I need a way to add a `userID` field to each document based on the object. So let's say the collection has this data:

```
[
    {
        _id: "111",
        ...
    },
    {
        _id: "333",
        ...
    },
    {
        _id: "555",
        ...
    }
]
```

The document should end up looking like this:

```
[
    {
        _id: "111",
        userID: "222",
        ...
    },
    {
        _id: "333",
        userID: "444",
        ...
    },
    {
        _id: "555",
        userID: "666",
        ...
    }
]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start with [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to get your dynamic object as an array of keys and values. Then you can use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to find matching pair, [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) to get single element:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            userId: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { 
                        match: { 
                            $arrayElemAt: [ 
                                { 
                                    $filter: { 
                                        input: { $objectToArray: {  111: "222", 333: "444", 555: "666" } }, 
                                        cond: { $eq: [ "$$this.k", { $toString: "$_id" } ] }
                                    } 
                                },
                                0 
                            ] 
                        }
                    },
                    in: "$$match.v"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Lc0-Bou6Wdr)

Comment: This object is dynamically generated with JavaScript before the aggregation, it isn't a part of the document: `{ 111: "222", 333: "444", 555: "666" }`. I'll edit my question to make it more clear

Comment: @APixelVisuals sorry for that, should be fine now